# How do I replace in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given

```
const allPost = [{_id: "uniqueId1", "name": "Bob"}, {_id: "uniqueId2", "name": "Sam"}]
const changeTo = {_id: "uniqueId1", "name": "Tim"}
```

I want to change to the given allPost object so it becomes

```
const allPost = [{_id: "uniqueId1", "name": "Tim"}, {_id: "uniqueId2", "name": "Sam"}]
```

I tried this but it does not work

```
const allPost = [{_id: "uniqueId1", "name": "Bob"}, {_id: "uniqueId2", "name": "Sam"}]
const changeTo = {_id: "uniqueId1", "name": "Tim"}
const newPost = allPost.filter((post) => {
    if(post._id === changeTo._id) {
        post = changeTo
    }

})
```

Anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you can use a `map` function like this:

```js
const allPost = [{_id: "uniqueId1", "name": "Bob"}, {_id: "uniqueId2", "name": "Sam"}]
const changeTo = {_id: "uniqueId1", "name": "Tim"}
const newPost = allPost.map((post) => {
    if(post._id === changeTo._id) return changeTo;
    else return post;
});
console.log(newPost);
```

Comment: Huh, "you cannot change `allPost` content"? Using the `const` keyword does not make the array immutable. You need to reword that phrase a bit.

Comment: As simpler as better... anyway if you try on snippet to make the map directly in const allPost you will get an error "you cannot change a const"...